# Algorithm verification: Get all the combinations of possible words

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification, algorithms, recursive-algorithms, python

I wanted to know if the algorithm that i wrotte just below in python is correct.

My goal is to find an algorithm that print/find all the possible combinaison of words that can be done using the character from character '!' (decimal value = 33) to character '~' (decimal value = 126) in the asccii table:

[image: ascii table]

Here the code using recursion in python:

```
byteWord = bytearray(b'\x20')  # Hex = '\x21' & Dec = '33' & Char = '!'

cntVerif = 0 

def comb_fct(bytes_arr, cnt: int):
    global cntVerif

    if len(bytes_arr) > 3:
        print(f'{cntVerif+1}:TEST END')
        sys.exit()

    if bytes_arr[cnt] == 126:
        if cnt == len(bytes_arr) or len(bytes_arr) == 1:
            bytes_arr.insert(0, 32)
        bytes_arr[cnt] = 32
        cnt += 1
        cntVerif += 1
        print(f'{cntVerif}:if bytes_arr[cnt] == 126: \n\tbytes_arr = {bytes_arr}')
        comb_fct(bytes_arr, cnt)

    if cnt == -1 or cnt == len(bytes_arr)-1:
        bytes_arr[cnt] = bytes_arr[cnt] + 1
        cntVerif += 1
        print(f'{cntVerif}:if cnt==-1: \n\tbytes_arr = {bytes_arr}')
        comb_fct(bytes_arr, cnt=-1)  # index = -1 means last index

    bytes_arr[cnt] = bytes_arr[cnt] + 1
    cntVerif += 1
    print(f'{cntVerif}:None if: \n\tbytes_arr={bytes_arr}')
    comb_fct(bytes_arr, cnt+1)


comb_fct(byteWord, -1)
```

Pseudo-code:

```
byteWord = bytearray(b'\x20')  # create a byte with value 20 in hex basis
cntVerif = 0  


def comb_fct(bytes_arr, cnt: int):
 
    if length(bytes_arr) > 3: 
        print(f'{cntVerif+1}:TEST END')
        stop

    if bytes_arr[cnt] == 126:
        if cnt == length(bytes_arr) or length(bytes_arr) == 1:
            bytes_arr.insert(index=0, value=32)  # Insert at the top of the byte array an other byte at index 0 (the begining) with value 32
        bytes_arr[cnt] = 32
        cnt += 1
        cntVerif += 1 
        print(f'{cntVerif}:if bytes_arr[cnt] == 126: \n\tbytes_arr = {bytes_arr}')
        comb_fct(bytes_arr, cnt)

    if cnt == -1 or cnt == len(bytes_arr)-1:
        bytes_arr[cnt] = bytes_arr[cnt] + 1
        cntVerif += 1
        print(f'{cntVerif}:if cnt==-1: \n\tbytes_arr = {bytes_arr}')
        comb_fct(bytes_arr, cnt=-1)  # index = -1 means last index

    bytes_arr[cnt] = bytes_arr[cnt] + 1
    cntVerif += 1  
    print(f'{cntVerif}:None if: \n\tbytes_arr={bytes_arr}')
    brute_force_fct(bytes_arr, cnt+1)


comb_fct(byteWord, -1)
```

Thank your for your help because python allow just a limited number of recursion (996 on my computer) so for exemple i can't verify if my algorithm give all the word of length 3 that can be realised with the range of character describe upper.
And more generally i would like to know if my algorithm is correct genrally (the logic).

Of course if anyone has a better idea to writte this algorithm (a faster algorithm for exemple). I will be happy to read it.

Comment: Is there a fixed length of the word?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews
Thk for your answer. No, not necessarily  as i just want to know if by running this code (so  theorically an infinite number of time) this algorithm will print/ give me all the possible word. 

But in a practicall way i wanted to test this algorithm on word of length 3.

Comment: Any way you could translate this into pseudocode for us? I know Python is basically pseudocode, but I am having trouble deciphering.

Comment: @MikeEarnest ok i am goign to edit my message to edit it and to add pseudo code

Comment: @MikeEarnest I ve just one it tell me if it is better

Comment: I'm still lost. On a math questions website, pseduocode is typically like [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3811602/loop-in-a-pseudocode) or [that](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2621541/recursive-proof-by-induction-with-pseudocode). No f-strings please. Byte codes are not for pseudocode, use a list of integers instead.  Just my two cents.

Comment: This is a python built-in. The documentation also gives python code for the equivalent algorithm. https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product

Comment: @Karl Thank a lot. It seems very interesting. But i still would like to know if my algorithm is correct.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I ve just poste an answer that i hope is correct. I think that this solution is simpler and optimal (in time). Can you please tell me if it is correct?

Comment: @Karl I ve just poste an answer that i hope is correct. I think that this solution is simpler and optimal (in time). Can you please tell me if it is correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT:  a full efficient python code (see the accepted answer):
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72762403/algorithm-verification-get-all-the-combinaison-of-possible-word

**EXPLANATION:**

To solve this problem i think that i ve found a more elegant and faster way to do it without using recursive algorithm.
*Complexity:*
I think too that it is the time and space optimal solution.
As it is in time: O(n) with n the total number of possible combinaison that can be **very very** high. And theorically O(1) in space complexity. Concerning  the space complexity because of the python language characteristics my code ,from a practical point of view, creates a lot of bytearray. This can be corrected with light modification. But for a better code check the solution posted by @ricci [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72762403/algorithm-verification-get-all-the-combinaison-of-possible-word/72776385#72776385) that i marked as the accepted answer.
*Mathematical principle used:*
I am using the fact that it exists a bijection between all the number in decimal basis and the number in base 94.
It is obvious that each number in base 94 can be written using a special sequance of unique character as the one in the range [30, 126] (in decimal value) in the ascii code.
*Exemple of base conversion:*
https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/decimal-to-hex.html
The operator '//' is the quotient operator and the operator '%' is the modulo operator.

I will be happy if anyone can confirm that my solution is correct. :-)

**ALGORITHM**

*VERSION 1:*
If you are NOT interested by getting all the sequence of words starting by '!'.
For exemple in lenght 2, you are NOT interested by the words of the form `'!!'...'!A' '!B' ... etc ...'!R'...'!~'` (as in our base '!' is equivalent to zero).

```
# Get all ascii relevant character in a list
asciiList = []
for c in (chr(i) for i in range(33, 127)):
    asciiList.append(c)
print(f'ascii List: \n{asciiList} \nlist length: {len(asciiList)}')


def base10_to_base94_fct(int_to_convert: int) -> str:
    sol_str = ''
    loop_condition = True

    while loop_condition is True:
        quo = int_to_convert // 94
        mod = int_to_convert % 94
        sol_str = asciiList[mod] + sol_str
        int_to_convert = quo
        if quo == 0:
            loop_condition = False

    return sol_str


# test = base10_to_base94_fct(94**2-1)
# print(f'TEST result: {test}')


def comb_fct(word_length: int) -> None:
    max_iter = 94**word_length

    cnt = 1
    while cnt < max_iter:
        str_tmp = base10_to_base94_fct(cnt)
        cnt += 1
        print(f'{cnt}: Current word check:{str_tmp}')


# Test
comb_fct(3)
```

*VERSION 2:*
If you are interested by getting all the sequence of words starting by '!'.
For exemple in lenght 2, you are interested by the words of the form  `'!!'...'!A' '!B' ... etc ...'!R'...'!~'` (as in our base '!' is equivalent to zero).

```
# Get all ascii relevant character in a list
asciiList = []
for c in (chr(i) for i in range(33, 127)):
    asciiList.append(c)
print(f'The word should contain only the character in the following ascii List: \n{asciiList} \nlist length: {len(asciiList)}')


def base10_to_base94_fct(int_to_convert: int, str_length: int) -> bytearray:
    sol_str = bytearray(b'\x21') * str_length
    digit_nbr = str_length-1
    loop_condition = True

    while loop_condition is True:
        quo = int_to_convert // 94
        mod = int_to_convert % 94
        sol_str[digit_nbr] = 33 + mod
        digit_nbr -= 1
        int_to_convert = quo
        if digit_nbr == -1:
            loop_condition = False

    return sol_str


def comb_fct(max_word_length: int) -> None:
    max_iter_abs = (94/93) * (94**max_word_length-1)  # sum of a geometric series: 94 + 94^2 + 94^3 + 94^4 + ... + 94^N
    max_iter_rel = 94
    word_length = 1

    cnt_rel = 0  # rel = relative
    cnt_abs = 0  # abs = absolute
    while cnt_rel < max_iter_rel**word_length and cnt_abs < max_iter_abs:
        str_tmp = base10_to_base94_fct(cnt_rel, word_length)
        print(f'{cnt_abs}:Current word test:{str_tmp}.')
        print(f'cnt_rel = {cnt_rel} and cnt_abs={cnt_abs}')
        if str_tmp == bytearray(b'\x7e') * word_length:
            word_length += 1
            cnt_rel = 0
            continue
        cnt_rel += 1
        cnt_abs += 1

comb_fct(2)  # Test
```